# $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^4}$ what upper bound does it yield for the error S-S30

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation, riemann-sum

The integral test enables us to bound the error approximation of the series 
$$S=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^4}$$

by the partial sum 
$$S30=\sum_{n=3}^{30} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^4}$$

What upper bound does it yield for the error S−S30 ? Give your answer accurate to 3  signiﬁcant digits.

SO I calculate  $$\int_{30}^ \infty \frac{dn}{n(\ln n)^4}$$ but the answer is wrong why appreciate any help

Comment: What did you get as your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You've included the $n=30$ term in your partial sum, so you don't want to count it again in your error term.

In more detail, to start the standard form of the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) takes the form

$$
\int_N^\infty f(x)\, dx \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)\leq f(N)+\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$

Letting $f(n)=\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^4}$, the error between the partial sum $S_{30}=\sum_{n=3}^{30}f(n)$ and the exact value infinite sum $S=\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n)$ is the tail of the series $S=\sum_{n=31}^\infty f(n).$ So this is the sum we want an upper bound for, which the integral test tells us is $f(31)+\int_{31}^\infty f(x)\,dx$.